# Disable Selectbox by Name in Document Ready - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am a beginner I am trying to disable my select box using its name not id when the page loaded however my below code is not working. I will really appreciate any advice thank you

```
<script>     
    $(document).ready( function(){
       document.getElementsByName("Selectabs").disabled=true;    
    });
</script>

<select id="Selectbc123" name="Selectabs">
   <option value="01" grouping="">01</option>
   <option value="02" grouping="">02</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByName("Selectabs")[0].disabled=true;`

`getElementsByName` returns an array of objects. That's why you should use position [0]

> The getElementsByName() method returns a collection of all elements in
>   the document with the specified name (the value of the name
>   attribute), as a NodeList object. The NodeList object represents a
>   collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers. The
>   index starts at 0.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp